# Does nginx support rtmpt/rtmpts?

Tags: nginx, streaming, video-streaming, embedded-linux, rtmp

I'm interested in getting the "rtmpt" and "rtmpts" protocol working
on a an embedded linux device (like a capture camera) 
where the embedded linux device acts a standalone rtmpt/rtmpts server.

So, I already have nginx rtmp module compiled (which is leightweight enough)
 and installed the linux device and verified plain old "rtmp" protocol 
streams fine with nginx as the server.

However, it wasn't clear to me if nginx supports "rtmpt" and "rtmpts".  If it does, is there some sample nginx.conf config for this?
If it does not, what other software do you think I can consider to add 
to get that to work on the embedded device?

Thanks for any ideas.

Henry

Answer (score 1):

As per the author, no.

https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/issues/279

It's from Oct 2013, but I can't find anything else to contradict this.